# Pros and cons of the LaTeX3 syntax?

Tags: programming, latex3, expl3

The programming language introduced by `expl3` in LaTeX3 is a bit unusual compared to other TeX macro languages in that it uses both _ and : for function names. Could someone provide some technical insight on the pros and cons of the syntax?

Comment: I don’t think this question is appropriate for this site (and no, I don’t have anything to do with the LaTeX3 project).

Comment: Not even as community wiki?

Comment: No, because I think it is an invitation for trolling.

Comment: A few comments from someone who is involved. (1) If you use `\fi:` in your own stuff then you are probably missing the point of `expl3`: I'm pushing for a lot less 'exposure' of the renamed primitives in the documentation. (2) I think this is a discussion best had elsewhere, for example the LaTeX-L list. (3) I suspect that in any case this is likely to be subjective. CW isn't meant to be a way to 'get around' that type of thing. (4) Obviously, I'm not going to vote to close this question as it would be very questionable of me to do so!

Comment: @Caramdir and Joseph: I would like some insight from people having intimate knowledge of TeX. Do you see a way to rephrase the question?

Comment: @Joseph: LL is probably the wrong place because I think it will be biased.

Comment: I'm perfectly happy to provide an answer based on the questions I asked about the syntax. (I raised a number of similar questions myself on LaTeX-L around the time I was asked to join the team.) I'd point out that basic plan for the syntax predates my involvement by a *long* way.

Comment: @Joseph: please do. I understand L3 is a 'long-term' project ;)

Comment: I'm doing my best to reduce the 'long-term' business, honest :-)

Comment: @Caramdir: on the invitation to trolling, I think we can down vote them.

Comment: If I weren't a moderator, I would consider voting to close this as "too localised".  I'd be surprised to find many people here that could answer this question, in that I don't get the sense that many people have actually tried the LaTeX3 syntax.  So Joseph can (and has) given an excellent answer in his position as Resident LaTeX3 expert, but for the rest of us there's not a lot to learn from this question.

Comment: The revised question is a lot better, and if I could, I would remove my vote to close the question.

Comment: @Andrew, as I said I think overall this type of discussion is probably best (currently) reserved for somewhere like LaTeX-L, although the revised question is rather more focused as Caramdir observes. (I'd also point out that your comment suggests that JF has made a good answer: 'not used much, is it!'.)

Comment: I don't see the problem with this style of question. There are lots of other questions for which only one or two people here are capable of answering in detail.

Comment: @Will Robertson: That wasn't quite my point.  The original question was quite broad and vague but didn't (in my opinion) have a broad appeal. I wasn't convinced that many people would be interested in the answers.  A question with broad scope should have a broad appeal.  I'm less unhappy with the revised question.  It'll probably never appear on my list of top ten, but I wouldn't now vote to close.

Comment: @Joseph: Who's JF?  I meant your answer(s)!

Comment: 'JF' = Jonathan Fine. He's quite active in various places, so I tend to assume people know who he is. He did answer here, in my defense.

Comment: @Andrew: I think "too localized" is about there being too few people who would *benefit* from an answer, not about there being too few able to *provide* one.

Answer (score 18):

Disclaimer: originally the question was phrased as like/dislike instead of pros/cons, and that is the only way in which I can provide an answer. I do not have enough practical experience in expl3 to comprehend the technical (de)merits of the language. So this answer is an (outside) opinion piece only.

To readers that know my background as one of the luatex and ConTeXt developers it should come as no surprise that I do not like the new syntax.

My main objection is that it adds additional complexity to a task (macro programming) that is already highly complex.

Taking the definition of `\mode_if_horizontal:TF` as an example:

```
\prg_set_conditional:Npnn \mode_if_horizontal: {p,TF,T,F}{
   \if_mode_horizontal: 
   \prg_return_true: \else: \prg_return_false: \fi:
}
```

This looks like I would have to learn a completely new programming language that looks  similar to, but is clearly not the same as, TeX macros. Taking into account that it took me more than a year at a full-time job to learn how to write TeX macros properly, this scares me quite a bit.

In the example, the naming of the internal macros and the use of a comma-separated list suggest that the intent is to make macros behave more like functions in other languages would. But looking at expl3 as a beginner while already having a lot of knowledge of the underlying engine, I do not truly believe that the new syntax will succeed in shielding off the underlying engine. The problem is that if it fails to do that then it is not a replacement language, but an additional language that needs to be learned and used on top of the already existing macro language. And, at least to me, it is an additional language with *very* unfamiliar syntax and semantics.

All in all, I much prefer traditional TeX style macros with lua for more complex tasks.

Comment: You might be right that expl3 can only really be learned by those who already know how to program with TeX macros. The other side of expl3 is that it is essentially a library of higher level tools that what LaTeX gives you (which is higher level again than TeX), so *any* system along the same lines (etoolbox, etc.) has its own learning curve.

Comment: P.S.  I don't take huge pains to turn my code into expl3-only syntax. There's no problem at all with using `\def`, `\expandafter`, and others while also using expl3's data structures and conditionals.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But it is a library of higher level tools _using different language conventions_ so on top of having to learn the semantics of the new tool set, one also has to learn the syntax of the new tool set.

Comment: Every time this sort of discussion arises I'm left wondering if a better approach would be to go the way of something like etoolbox. You can imagine writing a 'better LaTeX kernel' in a more systematic way using e-TeX and providing thee tools while mainly using TeX primitives. But then I wonder if it really would be clear enough. In the end I'm left not knowing what to think!

Comment: **@Taco**: LaTeXe programming is so ad hoc it's hard to argue that it even has language conventions. I get that expl3 looks like it has a steep learning curve at first blush, but I don't think it's as bad as it looks. But I'm certainly going to admit it's not for everyone. **@Joseph**: I think expl3 is the right way to go `:)`

Comment: @Taco: The aim of insulating the documentwriter from the wonderful and frightening world of Plain Tex was there from the beginning.  This syntax adds the beginnings of a type system to the language, which in principle could mean useful abstract interpretation for Tex code, and, who knows, maybe useful error messages some day.  Of course, all this has been done for Lua already.

Comment: @Charles: doesn't that goal conflict with Will's remark about using `\expandafter`?

Comment: @Taco: I read that as saying that Will doesn't insulate himself.

Comment: There is a defunct expl3 module l3chk to perform run-time checking of the various type specifications in expl3 (intending for debugging/checking purposes) but it hasn't seen any use for a long time.

Answer (score 15):

(Note: the answer covers things that were in various versions of the question!)

The question asks about two main issues, the 'primitives renamed' idea and the 'argument specification'. Just as background, the `expl3` environment makes `_` and `:` 'letters' for inclusion in control sequences, and also ignores whitespace. Using `@` as a 'letter' has, at least in LaTeX2e, been somewhat unsystematic. The idea of using `_` and `:` is that their role is more defined, with `_` used to divide up function and variable names into readable 'blocks' and `:` used to show the arguments taken by a function.

On 'primitives renamed', in the main directly using the primitives is not the idea of the `expl3` language. In the question, the case

```
\ifXXX:Nno
  ...
\fi:
```

was given. To put things on a more concrete footing, the *current* `expl3` renames all of the primitive TeX `\if...` statements as, for example

```
\if_mode_horizontal: % \ifhmode
  ....
\else:
  ...
\fi:
```

The idea is, however, that the primitives should not really be used in most cases (outside of the kernel itself). So instead the recommended test would be

```
 \mode_if_horizontal:TF { true-code } { false-code }
```

for two branches or

```
\mode_if_horizontal:T { true-code }
\mode_if_horizontal:F { false-code }
```

for a single branch. I've argued that the documentation shouldn't even mention the 'renamed primitives' where there is a better alternative.

On the 'argument specification' idea, I should first say what it is. The idea of the `expl3` approach to naming functions is that letters and `_` are used to generate the name, and that `:` is then used to end the name and start a list of arguments. This can be used in a couple of ways. First, I've shown above how we can have three related functions

```
\mode_if_horizontal:T
\mode_if_horizontal:F
\mode_if_horizontal:TF
```

where the *name* is the same but the *arguments* are different. So the idea is that I can read the above an quickly see what the test is supposed to achieve.

The second part of the 'argument specification' idea is that it allows a systematic way to show expansion. An example is `\cs_set_nopar:Npn`, which is the `expl3` name for `\def`. In LaTeX2e we also have `\@namedef` as a shortcut for

```
\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname
```

but it is hard to extend this to all of the possibilities. The same idea in `expl3` is called `\cs_set_nopar:cpn`. Notice that the only difference is the argument specification:

```
\cs_set_nopar:Npn \ControlSequence    #1#2 { stuff here } 
\cs_set_nopar:cpn { ControlSequence } #1#2 { stuff here }
```

I can then go further, as `\edef` is specified in the above by using an 'x' in the last position rather than an 'n':

```
\cs_set_nopar:Npx \ControlSequence    #1#2 { stuff here } % \edef
\cs_set_nopar:cpx { ControlSequence } #1#2 { stuff here } % `\@nameedef`
```

Obviously there are more example that can be given for this, but that is best studied in something like 'expl3.pdf' or recent TUGBoat articles I've written.

The question asked if the community likes these ideas. On that, I can offer no real answer other than a personal perspective. There is of course a learning curve to the syntax, and that will put some people off. However, I think that it does address at least some of the issues with writing code in TeX.

The question also asked about the downsides. One obvious issue is that `_` is used by TeX for subscripts, and so there are some issues in coding subscripts with `expl3`. That can be got around using the normal TeX approach to generating tokens with awkward category codes: `\lowercase` (in `expl3` `\tl_to_lowercase:n`, at least at the moment). Obviously, this requires some knowledge of how to program TeX, and it would be best if an alternative was available.

There is also the point that `expl3` is still be altered as new things come up. While that means that useful changes can happen it also means you need to be prepared to keep up to date. Usually the changes are flagged up in the CTAN uploads but there is still a need to do testing with the current `expl3` release if you want to be sure things work.

(LuaTeX offers the possibility to program in Lua, which is obviously an alternative approach to `expl3`. That seems such a big difference that I'm not going to attempt to cover it in this answer!)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and examples. Sorry to change the question statement before your answer. Feel free to modify it to be in sync with your answer.

Comment: I think I'll leave it as-is, and see if there are any other comments on the particular choice of 'letters'.

Comment: Can always use \sb to get subscripts :-)

Comment: If _ is used to delineate namespaces, I think . is a better fit. Not only it is easier to type, it also makes expl3 code less like C.

Comment: Also . and : together looks more interesting. And maybe : can also be dropped. When my eyes scan to :, I think the function name is over.

Comment: Too late, practically speaking, to change, I'm afraid :)

Comment: Will's right. I get the feeling we could talk for 10 more years about `expl3` and not satisfy everyone, or even those people who like the basic idea at all. At some stage things do have to be decided, for better or worse. As I said somewhere, this is to some extent a matter of preference rather than a clear technical decision.

Answer (score 14):

#### Whitespace

When writing expl3 code, whitespace is ignored. This produces more readable code because you don't have comment chars littering the ends of most lines. Consider

```
\cs_set:Nn \foo: {
  \mode_if_math:TF {
    \foo_math:
  }{
   \foo_text:                
  }
}
```

And now:

```
\cs_set:Nn \foo: {%
  \mode_if_math:TF {%
    \foo_math:
  }{%
   \foo_text:                
  }%
}
```

It might not seem much, but it takes away the cognitive burden of dealing with whitespace problems. You can change your indentation/brace style without worrying if you need to add `%`, and more C-like brace syntax is possible without messes of `%` everywhere.

By the way, if you need to insert a space in expl3 code, you use the ~ char instead, which has catcode 10 for this purpose.

Comment: Catcode 10 means that ~~ is not two spaces?

Comment: That's right. But remember this is the programmer's interface -- it does not change the behaviour of ~ on the document/user level. expl3 has commands such as `\msg_four_spaces:` if you want more than one space in an error message or whatever.

Comment: Can you write \cs_set: Nn for \cs_set:Nn?

Comment: No, for efficiency the arg spec is "baked in" as part of the macro name.

Answer (score 10):

#### Argument specifications

One of the fundamental improvements of the expl3 syntax revolves around its use of *argument specifiers*; that is, what comes after the : in the function names.

These argument specifiers signify how the arguments to a function will be pre-processed before being executed upon. For example, TeX provides the \let primitive to copy the meaning of one control sequence to another.

```
\let \foo \bar
```

In expl3, this is written as

```
\cs_set_eq:NN \foo \bar
```

The "N" means an argument of a single token, and \cs_set_eq:NN in this case is the *base function* from which variants are created. For example, this is equivalent to the above:

```
\cs_set_eq:cc {foo} {bar}
```

What the "cc" is saying is that before being executing \cs_set_eq:NN, first take the two arguments and turn them into control sequences. Other variants in this case are :cN and :Nc. To write this in TeX syntax would be

```
\expandafter \let \csname foo\expandafter \endcsname \csname bar\endcsname
```

I hope you'll agree the expl3 version is more readable and maintainable.

Another argument specifier is "V", whose meaning is "take the next token and replace it with the data stored by that token". For example,

```
\def\baz{\foo}
\cs_set_eq:VN \baz \bar
```

The "V" arg spec works not only with token list variables (or macros) as above, but also with token registers, integers, and so on.

Now, it happens that \cs_set_eq:VN isn't defined out of the box in expl3. No problem, there is a generic method for creating new variants:

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_set_eq:NN {VN}
```

In brief, the full list of specifiers are

```
N n c V v x f o T F
```

The "T" and "F" specifiers don't do any expansion; they exist solely as a shorthand to signify true and false branches of a conditional. Please read the expl3 docs for more information.

While other programming tools for LaTeX convey similar ideas, the advantage in my eyes to expl3's approach is the generic and extensibility of the argument specifier syntax. Your package has a command that takes nine arguments? No problem at all to write

```
\cs_set:Nn \foo_something:nnnnnnnnn {...}    
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \foo_something:nnnnnnnnn {cxVnfcxcv}
```

Obviously ridiculous, but in practise very powerful and convenient.

Answer (score 9):

(Answering the question as revised.)

TeX does not provide any namespacing, and so there is only convention to keep the macros/variables of one package separate from another. Knuth introduced the idea of using an extra 'letter' in the plain TeX format, where he used `@` in names which were not intended for use in typesetting.  Both LaTeX and ConTeXt have continued to use the idea of one or more additional 'letters' for internal macros. At a technical level there is no reason to enforce such a separation: one could simply use variation of case to make the origin of macros obvious. For example, for a package 'foo' the usual LaTeX2e approach would be to use

```
\foo@internal@macro
```

while for `expl3` we might have

```
\foo_internal_macro:
```

but there is no reason not to simply use

```
\FooInternalMacro
```

from a purely technical point of view.

LaTeX2e uses `@` as a 'letter'. This is unfortunately not done systematically, with internal names often containing arbitrary numbers of `@` symbols. This does not make for clear code. However, this has nothing to do with the choice of symbol: `@` could be applied systematically. ConTeXt uses a few more 'letters', for example `!`, in code blocks and is more systematic.

The choice of `_` and `:` for `expl3` is to some extent arbitrary, although both symbols are seen in other programming languages. To my knowledge, `@` is much less used in this way. As TeX only relies on category code, the choice of `_` and `:` can be regarded as being one about readability. This is of course a highly subjective area!

One clear issue with using `_` is that it is used by TeX to indicate a subscript. The overlap between code (which `expl3` is intended for) and typesetting math (where `_` is needed for subscripts) is small. This means that an approach using the `\lowercase` primitive is possible when a `_` is needed inside a code block to indicate a subscript. However, you can argue that an alternative choice may have been better here.

Answer (score 8):

I see two potential problems with `expl3`. The first is one of readability. Not only are there a whole new set of macros to learn for the ones we already know, their names seem to have gotten longer and are more opaque. `\cs_set_nopar:Npn` is far less clear than `\def`. (For a better example, look at the definition of `\ExplSyntaxOff` and compare that to its second definition (whose purpose I don't follow) in the expansion of `\ExplSyntaxOn`. On the plus side, the second definition is a lot happier :D) Worse, `\cs_set_nopar:cpn` and `\cs_set_nopar:Npx` look extremely similar to `\cs_set_nopar:Npn`. Maybe this is easy to get passed with a little practice.

Of course, LaTeX 2e doesn't do so well with that last point either. `\@namedef` and `\@nameedef` look extremely similar.

The changes to `\if...` also seem strange, beyond just the name expansion and rearrangement. Maybe it's easy to work around, but the two arms of the if seem to get tokenized completely. This seems potentially bad.

The second potential problem is debugging. As we all know, debugging LaTeX is *painful*. Often, the best way is to use TeX's tracing ability and see what it is actually doing. Consider the following if statement.

```
\ifhmode T\else F\fi
```

It's a very simple piece of TeX code and if we look at the tracing output, that is reflected.

```
{\ifhmode}
{true}
{the letter T}
{\else}
```

(The false branch is similar except it says `the letter F` and `\fi`, but it also enters hmode so there is some text in the log about that.)

Now consider the corresponding piece of expl3.

```
\mode_if_horizontal:TF{T}{F}
```

Apart from the `if` not being at the beginning of the name (this name makes me think it is going to set some mode if something else is horizontal), it is as straight-forward as the first snippet. Unfortunately, the log output is far less clear.

```
\mode_if_horizontal:TF ->\if_mode_horizontal: \prg_return_true: \else: \prg_ret
urn_false: \fi: \c_zero \exp_after:wN \use_i:nn \else: \exp_after:wN \use_ii:nn
 \fi:
{\ifhmode}
{true}

\prg_return_true: ->\exp_after:wN \if_true: \tex_romannumeral:D
{\expandafter}
{\romannumeral}
{\else}
{\iftrue}
{true}
{\expandafter}
{\else}

\use_i:nn #1#2->#1
#1<-T
#2<-F
{the letter T}
```

I'm trying to imagine what this would look like for a complicated piece of code. The most confusing part is this could have been written very simply as

```
\def\mode_if_horizontal:TF{\ifhmode\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}
```

(substitute `\use_i:nn` and `\use_ii:nn` as necessary). It still wouldn't be quite as short, but at least it wouldn't be using `\romannumerial`.

Of course, it could be that it's just so much easier to write readable code that no one will ever have to look at TeX's execution.

Either way, I'm looking forward to seeing what LaTeX3 has to offer.

Comment: \cs_set_nopar is a special case of ugly because its name was chosen specifically because at the time we believed that the non-long version really didn't have much place in internal code. Use/compare \cs_set:Npn instead. With :Npx being too similar, I disagree -- you learn to "spot" these argument specifiers quite well due to the systematic nature of the language.

Comment: You're right that tracing is made more complex, but ive never had much luck tracing complex code anyway. (extending the trace package to simplify expl3 tracing would be a great idea.) The expl3 conditionals are quite neat, and you can use Boolean logic with when the tests are expandable.

Comment: I think the real problem I have with the argument specifiers is that unlike standard practice in programming languages which allow function overloading like C++ or Java, these macros are doing fundamentally different things based on their arguments. For example, if `foo` is an int and `bar` is a float, then one would expect `Set(foo)` and `Set(bar)` to behave roughly the same: setting something to the argument. In contrast, `\cs_set:Npn` `\cs_set:Npx` treat their arguments extremely differently, despite having the same _name_.

Comment: To be clear, I don't have a problem with `\cs_set:Npn` and `\cs_set:cpn`. They do the same thing. But maybe this is just something one gets used to.

Comment: I think you might have a slight misunderstanding of how the argument specifiers work. (something for us to improve in the docs.) not only do the argument specifiers say how many arguments there are, they also specify how they are to be expanded before being passed to the underlying functions. So \foo_something:c *means* take the argument, turn it into a csname, and then apply the base function \foo_something:N to it.

Comment: There has been some internal discussion about the branching tests. I'm in favour of using the definition you suggest for these simple cases. The complex code you see in the trace output is needed for the 'complex Booleans' stuff, but I'd prefer a simpler but faster approach myself.

Comment: The best part is I screwed up the "very simple" version. =)

Answer (score 1):

I've done a couple of Google searches.

1. [web search for mode_if_horizontal](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22mode_if_horizontal%22) produces 3 hits (not including this page, which hasn't been indexed yet).
2. [open source code search for mode_if_horizontal](http://www.google.com/codesearch?as_q=mode_if_horizontal) produces no hits.

Comment: If you'd searched for `\cs_set_nopar:Npn` you'd only have found the Project stuff, I think :-) `\mode_if_horizontal:TF` was possibly not the best choice of 'useful' functions: perhaps I should revise it. (EDIT: I see that all of the hits are back to the Project anyway.)

Comment: Now this page is the first hit for the former, and I see 9 in total for it. The latter gets a grand total of one hit -- and it's in Emacs lisp code (something to do with auctex, naturally).

Comment: Google now says "about 94 results" for the former. The latter produces an error.

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX3 (`expl3`) is very powerful since it provides plenty of useful functions for doing variant programming jobs. But its syntax is not perfect from my point of view.

The `_` characters are used for separating words in long function names. I don't think it is better than CamelCase naming. In my opinion `\ModuleSomeFunc` is more readable than `\module_some_func`.

The `:` characters are used for separating function names and their argument variants. Because TeX is a macro language but in many times we need to expand first some arguments of a function.

But there is still a better way to handle argument variants. In my [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package I try to replace argument variants in `expl3` with composite functions. Here is an example:

```
% latex3 code for comparison
\module_func:Nn \arga {argb}
\module_func:Ne \arga {argb}
\module_func:NV \arga \argb
\module_func:cn {arga} {argb}
\module_func:ce {arga} {argb}
\module_func:cV {arga} \argb
```

```
% functional code for comparison
\ModuleFunc \arga {argb}
\ModuleFunc \arga {\Expand{argb}}
\ModuleFunc \arga {\Value\argb}
\ModuleFunc {\Name{arga}} {argb}
\ModuleFunc {\Name{arga}} {\Expand{argb}}
\ModuleFunc {\Name{arga}} {\Value\argb}
```

Here `\Expand`, `\Value` and `\Name` are predefind functions. Since the evaluation of composite functions is from inside to outside, everything works as expected, just like other programming languages such as `lua`. I think this syntax is more friendly to normal users.